# Why do I get an "Ambiguous platform" error when using SeSAMe R package for mouse DNA methylation analysis?

Tags: r, sesame, illumina

I'm trying to analyze methylation data from the Illumina Infinium Mouse Methylation Array. I opted for SeSAMe since it seems to have built-in support for exactly this array. However, it seems that the platform is somehow ambigous. Some functions fail with the following error message:
"Error in inferPlatformFromProbeIDs(sdf$Probe_ID, silent = !verbose) :
Ambiguous platform. Please provide platform explicitly."

I generated sigDFs with
`sdfs = openSesame(idat_dir, func = NULL)`
and when I run for example
`inferSpecies(sdfs, return.species = TRUE)`
I get the mentioned error message. I tried to "provide platform explicitly" by generating the sigDFs with
`sdfs = openSesame(idat_dir, func = NULL, platform = "MM285")`
but with the same result.
I also tried to provid the species explicitly by
`sdfsm = updateSigDF(sdfs, species="mus_musculus")`
but that didn't help either. I should mention that I haven't tampered with the IDAT files in any way, and they were delivered by the quite trustworthy governmentally funded SciLifeLab, so I expect them to be correct. Furthermore, I've been able to run some analysis with minfi, so they really seem to be OK.

Comment: Did you add `platform="MM285"` to the function that actually produced the error? From looking at the source code what is happening is that the probe IDs don't uniquely identify one platform, so that doesn't have to mean that the data is invalid. But I don't think `openSesame` passes on the `platform` information to its output either.

Comment: Hello, yes, I tried that, but it doesn't seem to take that as input at all: inferSpecies(sdfs, return.species = TRUE, platform = "MM285")
Error in inferSpecies(sdfs, return.species = TRUE, platform = "MM285") : 
  unused argument (platform = "MM285")

Comment: I see, I'm not sure what the intended method is but it seems the package mainly use the `platform` attribute of the input, if present. You can try running `attr(sdfs, "platform") <- "MM285"` and then using `sdfs` as input?